# Слово "фольклор"

Tags: фонетика

Как правильно по нормам русского языка произносится слово "фольклор"? Понимаю, что в языке-оригинале Л смягчается, а как быть с русским? Ведь часто и по-русски говорят, смягчая Л: [фольклЁр].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Новом орфоэпическом словаре русского языка Т.Ф. Ивановой дается **фолькЛОр** и (допуст.) **фолькЛЁр**.